# Is it possible to set a class attribute from a System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton though code?

Tags: c#, htmlcontrols

I am looking for a way to add class attributes to a button so it can be styled, but I can't figure out how to do this from my code.

The `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton` has a `AttributeCollection` property but it's read-only, so that's no use to me.

`System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button` has a `CssClass` property, I need something like this for the `HtmlButton`. I can't use the button provided from the `WebControls` because I need to use the `InnerHtml` property of the `HtmlButton` to place a icon on the button, but I do want to be able to style it as well!

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the css class like this

```
theHtmlButton.Attributes["class"] = "yourClass";
```

You can use this method to set any attribute, including your own custom attributes.